# Correctly Chaining Multiple Commands of Different types. Like a binary tree

Tags: c#, algorithm, decision-tree

I have a Command pattern with commands that run in sequence. The execution of the program starts at one rootcommand (node) and all Commands of Type Root can have like a tree always 2 choices. If the execution of the program returns true, the execution will always move to another command or node of certain Type. Every node has a different type. So if execution is on Node of Type A and the program returns true , it will always move to another Class/Node of Type B. If the Execution returns false it will move to Node D. (the nodes are not necessarily A,B,C,D. But every type/subclass has always the same 2 nodes.

I tried to achieve this approximately like this in C#

```
    public ICommand CreateTree()
    {
        RootCommand = TypeA();
        // build the tree
        InsertCoinCommand   insertCoinCommand = new InsertCoinCommand();
        ShowProductCommand showProductCommand = new ShowProductCommand();
        MakeChangeCommand   makeChangeCommand = new MakeChangeCommand();
        ReturnMoneyCommand returnMoneyCommand = new ReturnMoneyCommand();
        FinalizeCommand       finalizeCommand = new FinalizeCommand();

        // backup commands
        insertCoinCommand .SetLeft(new ReturnMoneyCommand());
        showProductCommand.SetLeft(new ReturnMoneyCommand());
        returnMoneyCommand.SetLeft(new FinalizeCommand());
        makeChangeCommand.SetLeft(new FinalizeCommand());

        // commands chaining
        RootCommand.SetRight(insertCoinCommand)
                   .SetRight(showProductCommand)
                   .SetRight(makeChangeCommand)
                   .SetRight(returnMoneyCommand)
                   .SetRight(finalizeCommand);

        return RootCommand;
    }
    
    ... (i use like this)
    
    object.CreateTree().Execute();
    
    ...
```

the BASE / Abstract class from where derives all the commands is almost implemented like this

```
    public void Execute()
    {
        if (executeCommand()) 
            RightNode.Execute();
        else 
            LeftNode.Execute();
    }

    public abstract bool executeCommand();
```

Well this approach causes the application to crash some times because one of the 2 nodes doesn't exist.
What would a better way to chain those commands so that every single type knows in advance who is the left and right node ?

Comment: If every command has always left and right node, this will be an infinite loop. Is this intended? If not, you will need a null check `RightNode?.Execute();` and `LeftNode?.Execute();`

Comment: No. Not every node has a left or right. But It's intended that when all the commands ran, I want to restart from the beginning.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand how to build up this

Comment: This sounds very much like a state-machine, I.e. Each command would be a 'state' and Left/Right would be 'transitions' to a different state.  Exactly how you would build one would depend on your specific application.